# How to stop autorotion of selected subview in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, rotation

I have a View Controller I have started an AVCaptureSession on the view of the View Controller,

```
  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
```

Now I add it like this,

```
[self.view.layer addSubLayer: captureVideoPreviewLayer]
```

I also have added two buttons on storyboard in this View Controller, On rotation of the device the self.view should not rotate as it has the camera going on but I want the two buttons which are capture and cancel button to align and rotate,
How can I achieve this using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not as easy as it should be. You may not simply "not rotate" a single view while the rest of the UI is rotated.

Since you are using a camera I suggest you to capture the the device orientation change through the notification center while keeping the controller orientation locked to whatever is your default or current state.

On orientation change you should then try and rotate the view with your buttons or anything else that should rotate. This is best done if all of the controls are added to a single view which has the same size as the view controller and is centered in the view controller. This means the constraints for this view are `center x`, `center y`, `width`, `height`. You need outlets for width and height and set them manually in the code. When view will layout subviews (it is a method to override in the view controller) simply set the `width` and `height` to the same as is the view controller `controller.view.frame.size`. Till this point your application should look exactly the same as it does now if rotations are disabled.

Now for the fun part: You need to check the current orientation and apply a rotation transform on the view with the buttons. What you need is a property holding the current interface orientation and upon changing that orientation you should apply a different transform to the view. The device orientation will not give you the interface orientation as device orientation includes extra positions. So when device orientation changes you need to use a switch statements and only on the 4 orientations that make sense should you change the interface orientation.

Once you have all that you should create a method that takes a user interface orientation as input and and will reposition the view with the buttons. (assuming you use portrait by default) You need to swap the `width` and `height` when the interface orientation is landscape as in `widthConstraint.constant = controller.view.frame.size.height` and apply a rotation transform depending on the orientation.

This method should be called when:

- The controller will become visible with the application status bar orientation
- When view will layout with the same orientation as was previously saved from view will become visible or device orientation change
- When device orientation changes if the new orientation makes sense and is different then the currently set interface orientation

There are other ways of doing this though. For instance you may keep the rotation of the view controller and rotate the camera view with the same procedure and this is even easier since you may use `viewWillTransitionToSize` and `animateAlongsideTransition` but the animation will probably not be acceptable as you may see black parts when the view controller is oriented. Though I am not sure that will actually occur and even if it does it might be possible to fix it with disabling bound clipping on the controller view.